# What's the drainage of the canyon?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The canyon appeared to climb another thousand feet to a high,
> wind-ripped ridge. If his strength held, he might reach it by dusk.
> But even more than the looming threat of hunger and thirst, he feared
> what lay beyond that distant ridge at the top of the **drainage.**

Some kind of valley?

Comment: A **drainage basin** is any area of land where precipitation collects and drains off into a common outlet, such as into a river, bay, or other body of water.

Comment: Than you very much!

Comment: [*BSL Geography Glossary - **Catchment Area/Drainage Basin** - definition.*](http://www.ssc.education.ed.ac.uk/BSL/geography/catchmentareadrainagebasind.html)

Answer (score 0):

It refers to the canyon itself, which may have a stream, possibly intermittent, that drains an area. See the definitions:

[Merriam-Webster "canyon"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/canyon)

> : a deep narrow valley with steep sides and often with a stream flowing through it

[Merriam-Webster "drainage"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drainage)

> 3.: an area or district drained

The area beyond the "distant ridge" is furthest upstream, out of the canyon.

Comment: Than you very much!